# ebay-nodejs-Getting a User access token-Unexpected error occurred, please contact resource provider

Tags: node.js, api, ebay-api

I have a new problem about api integration with ebay. I want to get "user access token" but i could not. I have taken "Application Access Token", "User Consent" but not "User Access Token". I am working on node.js. As you can see my code below i am getting app access token and send it to get user access token. Api gives me an error which is "Unexpected error occurred, please contact resource provider". I am working on this for a long time. What is my problem and what should i do? Thanks.
I have read almost every document on ebay api documentation. I am doing the same things like their document below.
https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-authorization-code-grant.html

var axios = require('axios');
var qs = require("querystring");

```
//The client credentials grant flow

//https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-client-credentials-grant.html

axios("https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "Basic " + Buffer.from(
            //App ID (Client ID):
            `orcas`
        ).toString('base64')
    },
    data: qs.stringify({
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
        scope: "https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope",
        // parsed from redirect URI after returning from eBay,

    })
})
    .then(response => {
        console.log("Application data");
        console.log(response.data.access_token);

        axios("https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token", {
            method: "GET",
            header: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                Authorization: "Basic " + Buffer.from(
                    //App ID (Client ID):
                    `orcas`
                ).toString('base64')
            },
            data: qs.stringify({
                grant_type: "authorization_code",
                code: response.data.access_token,
                redirect_uri: "orcas"
            })
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log("res.data");
                console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("**************Get search error**************")
                console.log(err)
            });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("**************Get access token error**************")
        console.log(err)
    });
```

Comment: Use the hendt/ebay-api library https://github.com/hendt/ebay-api for this.  I had similar issues with the User token vs Application tokens.  All were solved for me thru use of that library.